# 'then' expected near ',' but I already place then with Lua

Tags: lua, pico-8

As a complete beginner I'm experimenting on a small code on Pico-8 :

```
function _update()
if p.x, p.y == 64, 45 then
 cls()
    print("dead", 37, 70, 14)
 end
end
```

And when I try to run the program an error message appear which says :

```
'then' expected near ','
```

I've searched a lot but never found an answer. Can somebody help?

Comment: This isn't valid Lua.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use an `if` formatted:

```
if p.x, p.y == 64, 45 then
  [...]
end
```

You can assign values to multiple variables with syntax a little like what you've used here. For example,

`p.x, p.y = 64,45` would set `p.x` to `64` and `p.y` to `45`. But you can't check for equality on multiple variables in that way. You need to check each variable separately:

```
if p.x == 64 and p.y == 45 then
  [...]
end
```

Your code tries to use `p.x, p.y == 64, 45` as a condition for your `if` branch. This doesn't work because lua doesn't understand this to mean `p.x == 64 and p.y == 45`. Instead it understands it as a list of unrelated statements (`p.x`, `p.y == 64`, and `45`), and trips up on the comma between `p.x` and `p.y`.

Comment: You got the answer in just as I was typing - my apologies!

Comment: @Brian happens often enough, no need to apologise!

Comment: the program runs now but i can't move and the two "characters" spawn at the same place

Comment: @The_berrichon That sounds like an unrelated problem, even if it's in the same program as the thing you originally asked about. StackOverflow comments are designed for clarification or suggesting improvements, and aren't convenient for follow-up questions and additional answers. You should open a new question devoted to the new problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning values to variables this way is ok:

`a, b` = 1, 2

For the `if` statement though, you'll need to do this:

```
if a == 1 and b == 2 then
    -- do something
end
```

Comment: Sure. The `and` operations can also be combined with other boolean operators.